# SQL conditional where clause with single date and date range

Tags: sql, sybase, where-clause

Using Sybase.

I have a store procedure accepting multiple parameters.

@param1 and @date1 will always have values, but @param2, @param3, and @date2 are optional.

I have written something like this.

```
(@param1, @param2, @param2, @date1, @date2)

SELECT * FROM table
WHERE col1 = @param1
AND col2 = COALESCE(NULLIF(@param2,''), col2)
AND col3 = COALESCE(NULLIF(@param3,''), col3)
AND
IF(@date2 is empty)
  col4 = @date1
ELSE
  col4 IS BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2
```

Looking help with writing the last part. If condition with dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if` doesn't belong there.  And it isn't needed:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE col1 = @param1 AND
     col2 = COALESCE(NULLIF(@param2,''), col2) AND
     col3 = COALESCE(NULLIF(@param3,''), col3) AND
     ( (@date2 IS NULL AND col4 = @date1) OR
       col4 IS BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2
     )
```

Comment: Your solution worked! I used the "IF" expression to only convey how I expected it to work. You have helped me in past. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant way would be to write the last part as:

```
AND col4 between @date1 and coalesce(@date2, @date1)
```

This way if @date2 is null the condition would work like:

```
AND col4 between @date1 and @date1
```

which is equal to:

```
AND col4 >= @date1 and col4 <= @date1
```

which is equal to:

```
AND col4 = @date1
```

Comment: Your solution worked too and looks much cleaner. Thank you so much!

Comment: If is also better for the optimizer than using OR. Check the query plan.